# Does a matrix have a saddle point if it is not a payoff matrix?

Tags: optimization, game-theory

> Wikipedia claims: *"a saddle point of a matrix is an element which is both the largest element in its column and the smallest element in its row"*.

Lots of programming puzzles also talk about finding the saddle point of a matrix.
But I can't find any use for (or discussion of) a matrix saddle point except as a property of a payoff matrix for a two-player zero-sum game.

What I think has happened is that this definition was written in the context of two-player zero-sum payoff matrices (where it is useful) and that somebody picked up the idea as a programming exercise and now lots of texts talk about the "saddle point of a matrix" even though the definition is not useful outside of this context.

Am I missing something?

- Is this definition of a saddle point of a matrix useful in other contexts?
- Is there a nice connection between the concept of a saddle point of a matrix and the concept of a saddle point on the surface of a function (a critical point that is not a local minima or local maxima)?

Thanks!

Comment: I think mainly that the definition of "saddle point" here is not much linked to the algebra of matrices but is using "matrix" as a synonym for an array of numbers. I also think that the game theory aspect is not a trivial thing.

Comment: The connection to the saddle point of a surface is obvious. Take a matrix of discrete points.

Comment: I'm not familiar with what the analogue of a control point is for a function over a discrete domain, so I don't know how to convert the saddle point of a surface definition to a matrix.

Some of the ideas that I did try out seemed linked only in the sense that both are looking at minima and maxima, but the surface definition will not accept local or global maxima while the matrix one will.